# Multiple Inheritance - why does output is not as per MRO

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      print("A")

class B():
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      print("B")

class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      print("C")

c=C()
print(C.mro())
```

The output of print mro is Class C, Class B, Class A and Class Object.
As per that it should come something as C,B,A.
But the actual output coming as C,A,B.
Why is that?
Is it because of super?

Comment: The MRO affects method lookup; it has little or nothing to do with execution order.

Answer (score 2):

### What is class `C`'s MRO?

The Method Resolution Order of a class can be found by getting its `__mro__` attribute. Here is what C's MRO is:

```py
C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

However, when creating an instance of class `C`, this is what happens:

```py
c = C()
A
B
C
```

The actual output, as seen above, is A, B, C, not C, A, B. But this is still not what was expected, and it is different to the MRO.

### What is going wrong?

In each class, `super().__init__()` is called **before** `print("...")` is. Therefore, the order that the letters are printed out in effectively gets reversed.

Here is a diagram to explain what is happening:

```
__main__      C.__init__()      B.__init__()      A.__init__()      object.__init__()

  START
 c = C()    ->    START
           super().__init__()  ->   START
                             super().__init__()  ->   START
                                               super().__init__()   ->   START
                                                    print("A")     <-     END
                                  print("B")     <-    END
                print("C")     <-    END
   END      <-     END
```

Because the `print()` calls happen after the `super().__init__()` calls, the letters are printed in reverse order.

### How to produce the correct result

In order to get the correct the result, the order of the lines within each `__init__()` method must be reversed so that the letter is printed out before the next class' `__init__()` is called.

The following code would produce the expected output:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
      print("A")  # The print() line comes first
      super().__init__()  # The super().__init__() line comes second

class B():
    def __init__(self):
      print("B")
      super().__init__()

class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self):
      print("C")
      super().__init__()

c = C()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Yes it will print A, B , C
why is it taking Class A first while in the heritance Class B is first in order?
Can you please help me understand the flow with super once?
That would be really helpful.

Comment: Because in class B's `__init__()` method, `super()` is called before `"B"` is printed out. This means A's `__init__()` method gets called while B is still yet to call `print("B")`, so `print("A")` is called first.

Comment: I will add a sort-of diagram to the answer in a few minutes